# Is there a good alternative to apostrophe s in file name?

Tags: windows-10, filenames

If an one file named `zelda's_sword.jpg` is here, is there a good character or convention to replace `'s`?

I know that `sword_of_zelda.jpg` will be good alternative but I don't want for several reasons.

Comment: No apostrophe? ex. `zeldas_sword.jpg`. This is what I personally use. I find that (for me) it is typically pretty clear from context what is and isn't actually a plural noun.

Comment: @Anaksunaman I agree that the context can tell if it is plural or possessive. But I want to have certain delimiter if it is. Because some names like `brooks_sword`(brook and brooks are exist names) are difficult to distinguish between `brooks_sword` and `brook's sword`.

Comment: Any specific reason that you need to avoid the apostrophe for? It _is_ a valid filename on most operating systems.

Comment: @user1686  I'd use wsl, so I want to dodge to use it. As I know, Linux dose not allow to use apostrophe in file name(If I want, I have to do bothersome preprocessing likes escape.).